# Calling set_error_handler to define a class method to handle error

Tags: php, custom-error-handling

So I've been through stackoverflow once or about a billion times trying to find the answer to my problem but ive been unsuccessful so far. He're the problem. I'm calling a method of an error handling class using trigger_error. for whatever reason the error triggers without calling the function ive defined. please help. here's my code

```
class runtime_errors
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        //  Calling required files
        include_once(ROOT."/inc/php/pac/browser_detect.php");
        include_once(ROOT."/inc/php/func/display_as.php");

        //  Setting needed class functions
        $this->browser      =   new BrowserDetection();
        $this->display_as   =   new display_as();

        //  if available we're going to set the query string
        if(isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']))
            $this->query_string = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
        else
            $this->query_string = NULL;


        //  Setting this class and function as the error_handler, the & is important
        set_error_handler(array(&$this, 'log_error'));
    }

    public function log_error($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline)
    {
        echo 'am i working?';
    }
}
```

Comment: Are u  creating an instance of the class `runtime_errors`?

Comment: I've included the class in the constructor of another class and created an instance of the error handler class almost directly afterwards.

Comment: I see. U are using `$this` in the `constructor`,  but `$this` will only reflect the instance when the `ctor` is done working. U should try and switch this up. Try this : In the other class where u create the instance do lik ethis : `$o = new runtime_errors(); set_error_handler($o, 'log_error');
If that works u could a static function in your runtime_error class that initialise an instance and sets the error_handler. I hope i'm clear on this :)

Comment: I understand perfectly, fortunately I didn't need to use that method. After i replied i started tinkering with the classes again and noticed a few things. (1) My error handler class didn't output errors directly but stored them in the class which allowed me to display them without disrupting the flow of the page. (2) I was calling that function (the display error function) in the constructor of the class which initialized the new instance of the error handling class

Comment: This means in most cases I was requesting error messages before they were created. I moved the err_display so that it runs along side the destructor and everything seems to be working again

Comment: @KwesiO.Nkromah can you publish your new version?